# Effective algorithm for multiplying matrix and vector

Tags: algorithms, matrix-equations

I've got two matrices $n\times n$: $A$ and $B$ and a vector $v$ and I want to find the result of: $(A^2-B)\cdot v$ and I know it can be done in $O(n^2)$ time but don't know how. Straightforward algorithm would firstly find the matrix $A^2-B$ and then multiply it by $v$ in $O(n^2)$ time, but the first action would take time $O(n^3)$ (even if smaller by some trick, it would not be $O(n^2)$). Can anybody help me come up with and algorithm that works in $O(n^2)$ time?

Comment: In general, computing $A^2$ is going to take more than $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ time -- there is no known general algorithm for matrix multiplication as $n^2$. If $A$ has some nice properties (symmetric? diagnoalizable?), you can do better. Can you elaborate on where $A$ and $B$ come from?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ and even $v$ can be any form, that's the problem. Sill someone told that $(A^2-B)\cdot v$ can be computed in $O(n^2)$ time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can compute $Av$ in $O(n^2)$ time, then finding $(A^2-B)v$ is just doing this three times, with a subtraction. Now, if you want to compute this for lots of vectors, at some point it's faster to just save the matrix $A^2-B$ for future computations. But for just one, three matrix multiplications is faster.

Comment: "is just doing this three times, with a subtraction" - I don't understand this part, how three times? After computing $Av$ I have a vector, so $(A^2-B)v \neq (Av)\cdot (Av) - Bv$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You compute $w = Av$, then $x = Aw$, then $y = Bv$, then $z=x-y$. The first three steps are all $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Not sure where your $w$ comes in, nor why It's clear that $z = x - y = Av-Bv$ is at all helpful.

Comment: The $w$ is just $A^2v$. The point is that I don't have to compute the product in order to apply it twice to a single vector.